# rectangle list what is the syntax check for collision using intersect

Tags: c#, collision-detection, xna-4.0

I would like to now how to detect collision with lists of rectangles.

```
    Rectanlge Player;
    List<Rectangle> BlockHitBox =  new List<Rectangle>();
```

I don't know the proper syntax for.

```
BlockHitBox.Intersect<>();
```

The code should detect if the rectangle hit boxes collide with the player hit box.

My goal is to make a room from small rectangles that the player cant pass through them so i need to detect more then one collision at a time ( for corners)

Comment: it depends if you want: 1) all rectangles should hit 2) it's enough only one hits. after you know this, just iterate over. If you want fancy LINQ statement, search for `All`, `ForEach`, `Single`....

Comment: `Intersect` is probably not what you want here. It is used to return the common items between two `IEnumerable` objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `IntersectsWith` method of the `Rectangle` object like so:

```
var commonSize = new Size(100, 100);
var player = new Rectangle(new Point(0,0), commonSize);
var blockHitBox = new List<Rectangle>
{
    new Rectangle(new Point(0, 100), commonSize), // This one will not collide
    new Rectangle(new Point(100, 0), commonSize), // This one will not collide
    new Rectangle(new Point(0, 99), commonSize) // This one will collide
};

bool collision = blockHitBox.Any(item => item.IntersectsWith(player));
```